# sample code for Location finder in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to make an app which uses both the GPS and the magnetometer for finding the way and direction for mecca (Mosque). It has some special features like date picker for upcoming prayers, prayer timings left calculated from current location time zone and weather on the current location and some more on. If anyone has sample code regarding to this, please reply.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The magnetometer can be told just to return the current device heading, via [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html). It can return in unfiltered 3d, but there's no reason to use it — from [CLHeading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) just use the `trueHeading` property. That'll give you the same information shown in the Compass app.

To work out the heading to Mecca from where you are, you can use the formulas given [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Google Maps gives me a geolocation of about 21.436, 39.832 for Masjid al-Haram (I'm not sure it's terribly accurate, so I've rounded inappropriately low), so you could get the bearing from whatever location CLLocationManager tells you you're at something like:

```
#define toRadians(x) ((x)*M_PI / 180.0)
#define toDegrees(x) ((x)*180.0 / M_PI)

...

double y = sin(toRadians(39.832 - currentLocation.longitude)) * cos(toRadians(21.436));
double x = cos(toRadians(currentLocation.latitude)) * dsin(toRadians(21.436)) -
           sin(toRadians(currentLocation.latitude)) * dcos(toRadians(21.436)) * dcos(toRadians(39.832 - currentLocation.longitude));
double bearing = toDegrees(atan2(y, x));
```

You can then rotate a pointer on screen by the difference between the device's heading and the one you've just calculated. Probably easiest to use a CGAffineTransform on a UIView's [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) property.

That's all typed as I answer by the way, not tested. I'd check it against a reliable source before you depend on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tommy. but actually i need the Complete requirements and steps to develop that Mecca finder. can u please guide me?